# Java: Determine if the user has stopped typing

Tags: java, text, typing

I'm creating a simple text editor in Java and I'm trying to add undo and redo functionality. I want the program to be able to determine if the user has stopped typing in the text area, not just whether they have entered a character. The program should save a single character only if it was the only thing they typed. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Its a good idea. Do you know javax.swing API?

Answer (score 2):

Define "stopped typing".

Bascially, I'd think about using a timer.  Take each character event, add a counter and a timer that restarts every time there's a Key Up event.  Define "stopped typing" as when enough time has passed.

Then think if you *really* want to do it that way, 'cause it sounds like something that would drive me absolutely torches-and-pitchforks-to-the-developer's-house mad.

Comment: Good suggestion, and good point about thinking about if this is really what you, or more importantly, your users want. Be very careful with automating things too much. You don't want to wind up with something like Word which seems to randomly re-format text when you trigger its obscure rules.

Answer (score 0):

somewhere in a main class;

```
public static long lastKeyPressTime = 0l;
```

in your KeyListener interface;

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
   lastKeyPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

and finally, in an appropriate, fast running thread;

```
if((system.currentTimeMillis() - lastKeyPressTime) > 2000) {
   //do something, because the user hasnt typed for two seconds
}
```

Comment: This isn't thread safe as is.  `lastKeyPressTime` should probably be marked `volatile` here, so that writes to it from the EDT are observed by the "fast running" thread.